# Set up NewRelic on DNN 7 running in azure web app

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke, azure-web-app-service, newrelic, dotnetnuke-7

I have tried to get new relic to run inside my dnn 7 installation which runs in Azure web app.

I created a NewRelic account from the Azure portal and then I followed [the directions here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/azure-installation/azure-web-apps#manual)

The following APP SETTINGS were created in the configure tab of my web app:

```
NEWRELIC_LICENSEKEY : ****I used the one from my account*-*****
NEWRELIC_HOME:        C:\Home\site\newrelic
COR_PROFILER_PATH:    C:\Home\site\newrelic\NewRelic.Profiler.dll
COR_PROFILER:         {71DA0A04-7777-4EC6-9643-7D28B46A8A41}
COR_ENABLE_PROFILING: 1
```

I then added the explicit app name to the web config, as instructed from the documentation link above, because I have the "Always On" enabled for my webapp

No data appeared even after restarting my web app numerous times.

So then I tried to set it up in the New Preview Azure Portal (am I the only one who hates the new portal, seems needlessly complicated.).  I followed [the instructions for the new portal here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-new-relic-web-sites-dotnet-application-performance-management/).  This did not work either.

I manually uploaded the newrelic folder to the site root, and azure root folders and no success eighter.  No logs are generated.

Can someone help me figure out what I am missing and why I can't get NewRelic to run in my DNN 7 azure web app.

Thanks in advance.

Jordan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

My web app was set to run 64 bit.  The ddn site is not set up as a web project so I could not use NuGet to install a package.  What I did was create a blank project and install the NewRelic [package for 64 bit azure webapp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NewRelic.Azure.WebSites.x64/)

I than copied the files from that project and uploaded it into the site root of my web app, followed the instructions about manual install and restarted my website.

It now works.